# pyramid CSRF token changes from GET to POST

Tags: python, csrf, pyramid

I'm working on using the python requests module to login to a webpage.  I'm getting the `csrf_token` by doing a `GET` request on the url, parsing it with `BeautifulSoup` to get the `csrf_token` which is fine and working great, but when I do a `POST` and use the `csrf_token` from the `GET`, the `csrf_token` has changed and I can't login with an invalid `csrf_token`.

I understand `csrf` changes from `GET` to `GET` but shouldn't change from `GET` to `POST`.
How do I get the csrf_token to not change?  I do have access to the source too, but I didn't write it.

When I step into the code with `pdb.set_trace()` I can change the `csrf_token` to what I got from the `GET` and continue then everything works.

here is the requests code I have:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#~ URL       = 'https://portal.bitcasa.com/login'
URL       = 'http://0.0.0.0:12080/login'
EMAIL     = 'foo@foo.com'
PASSWORD  = 'abc123'
CLIENT_ID = 12345

client = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr})

# Retrieve the CSRF token first


soup = BeautifulSoup(client.get(URL).content)
csrftoken = soup.find('input', dict(name='csrf_token'))['value']

print csrftoken

# Parameters to pass
data    = dict(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD, csrf_token=csrftoken)
headers = dict(referer=URL)
params  = dict(client_id=CLIENT_ID)


r = client.post(URL, data=data, headers=headers, params=params)

print r
print r.text
```

I can login to other web pages with this method.

What other information can I provide to help you help me?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know the token has changed? Pyramid may reject the token for other reasons, perhaps?

Comment: I'm using `pdb.set_trace()` right before the `csrf` check and watching it change from `GET` to `POST`

Comment: The CSRF token code just looks it up in the session, there is nothing there to differentiate between `POST` and `GET`. Is there a valid session being maintained?

Comment: I believe the session is correct, I've posted it above, and have used it for other websites with success.

Comment: Are you controlling the server here as well? Is the server using `request.session.get_csrf_token()` or perhaps `request.session.new_csrf_token()` as well?

Comment: I'm using the `pserve` command to run the server, so the stock server.   grep for `request.session.get_csrf_token()` through all code returns 1 hit while `request.session.new_csrf_token()` returns 0. So it doesn't look like it's regenerating the `csrf`

Comment: You need to check if the session is changing between requests. I suspect that setting the `headers` on `client.POST` is overriding any implicit headers that would be sent (including the session cookie).

Comment: @Jeff: No, that just means that nothing will be *resetting* the token. Next thing to check is if a [session factory](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/sessions.html) has been configured.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel: No, `requests` maintains the headers and the referrer is *added* to the client session. Cookies will be preserved.